# jCryption ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jcryption

Our security team asked me to not submit `plain text` passwords in my log in page, we use HTTPS though. so I thought that I need to do client side encryption before submit, I searched for solution and decided to implement [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/). 
However the example presented there is PHP/python, after a few google found [this](https://github.com/JakeJP/jCryption.NET). I did whatever was explained in the link but I don't know how to retrieve form data that user submitted in form.
[image: screenshot of my login post back action]

I only see a `key` returns in my login post back action and the `LoginModel` that should contain username, password is null.

**Login.cshtml**

```
@model Portal.Model.Membership.LoginModel
@using jCryption

@{
    Layout = null;
    jCryption.HandleRequest(Request);
}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/global/plugins/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @jCryption.RenderScriptFor("form", src: @Url.Content("~/Assets/admin/scripts/jquery.jcryption.3.1.0.js"))
</head>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "placeholder" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-input", autocomplete = "off" })
            <span></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "placeholder" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-input", autocomplete = "off" })
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
    </div>
}
</body>
<!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

**Update**
I put break point on login post action and it popup twice, one with `key` and another with `jCryption`:
[image: jCryption form data after submit]

Answer (score 0):

For MVC 5, you need to adjust a little bit.
at login.cshtml

```
    @using jCryption
    @{
        jCryption.HandleRequest(Request);
    } 

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jcryption.3.1.0.mod.js"></script>     

        <script type="text/javascript">

        // tweak for compatibility with jquery.validate

            (function($){
                var _jCryption = $.jCryption;
                var jCryptionMod = function(el,options){
                    var form = $(el), hasValidator = !!form.data('validator');
                    if (hasValidator){
                        var v = form.validate();
                        var prev_handler = v.settings.submitHandler;
                        v.settings.submitHandler = function (_form, event) {
                            if( prev_handler ) prev_handler.apply(this, arguments);
                            var form = $(_form);
                            if (!form.hasClass('jc-before-submit')) {
                                v.settings.submitHandler = prev_handler;
                                form.addClass('jc-before-submit');
                                setTimeout( function(){ form.trigger('_jc_submit', event); }, 100 );
                            }
                        };

                        _jCryption.call(this, form, $.extend(options, {
                            submitElement: form,
                            submitEvent: '_jc_submit',
                            beforeEncryption: function(){
                                form.removeAttr('disabled');// form element hack ( IE11 )
                                return true;
                            }
                        }));
                    } else {
                        return _jCryption.call(this,el,options);
                    }
                }
                $.extend(jCryptionMod, $.jCryption);
                $.jCryption = jCryptionMod;
            })(jQuery);
        </script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var form = $('form');
                var url = form.attr('action') || '/Account/Login';
                form.jCryption({
                    getKeysURL: url + '?getPublicKey=true',
                    handshakeURL: url + '?handshake=true'
                });
            });
        </script>       
    }
```

AccountController, you should follow JakeJP's documentation (exact same code).

At IE F12 Developer Tools (Network-->go to detail view-->Request body), it showns &jCryptionKey= but not &UserName= and &Password=.

Answer (score 0):

You lack the `jCryptionHandler` attribute in your action method. The attribute is responsible for handling the jCryption handshake and decryption.

```
[jCryptionHandler]  
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```